# Backticks in a function that gets called in render

Tags: reactjs, backticks

What am I doing wrong here ? I'm returning `return children;` in a function which gets called in render()

```
children.push(<img key="`${this.data_images.hits[i].id}`" src="`${this.data_images.hits[i].previewURL}`"/>)
```

> Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `${this.data_images.hits[i].id}`

And the rendered output is

```
<img src="`${this.data_images.hits[i].previewURL}`">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"`${this.data_images.hits[i].id}`"
```

this is simple string
if you want to get your template work - you need to remove qoutation and past {} instead.

So code would be

```
children.push(<img key={`${this.data_images.hits[i].id}`} src={`${this.data_images.hits[i].previewURL}`}/>)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Is this specific to React ?

Comment: template literals is vanilla js feature, but it is required to chose - if you need plain string then you use `'` or `"` but if you want to make a template then use - `